# How to string to shared preference without an editText?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

can I save strings to my sharedpreference without using an editText. Using an edit text this is the format of putting string to the shared preference right?

```
editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
```

I want to happen is to get the users ID from the db for it to be saved on the sharedpreference.

```
editor.putString("userID", *******);
```

what should I put there? Thanks. I don't know how to do it.

And this is my db for the users.

[myDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YnjE.png)

Comment: Of course! Did you try it? It would've taken you lesser time to try than to write this question. Btw, put a `String` instance there.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

```
String valueToBeSaved = etUsername.getText().toString();
editor.putString("userID", valueToBeSaved); 
editor.apply();

DatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(Activity.this);
myDatabaseHelper.openDataBase();
String userId = myDatabaseHelper.getYourData(); //this is the method to query user UserId 
myDatabaseHelper.close(); 
//now save userId in shared preferences
String valueToBeSaved = etUsername.getText().toString();
editor.putString("userID", userId); 
editor.apply();
}
```

I hope youe are searching for this. If any doubts let me know.

Comment: Yes.. that you can get it from database

Comment: Is your user id auto created or are you creating it?

Comment: ok then you need to get that from database and then you need to save it in shared preferences

Comment: in your database helper class write a method which gets you user id

Comment: Will I create a new class that is DatabaseHelper?

Comment: Ohh, okay sir okay sir. :)

Comment: Uh, sir can I open my database from a webhost? Because I didn't used the internal database of the android studio..

Comment: means are you having database in server??

Comment: Yes sir from a server. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes definitely, for that you need to write a script and then you need to get the value. Which database are you using?

Comment: MYSQL database. What script should i do sir?

Comment: you have to write a script using php or other language and call that script from activity to get the value

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.putString("userID", parameter);
```

yes, in second parameter you can save your sting whatever your want.

Comment: What if I will get an item from my db? not from an editText? I that possible? O.o

Comment: yes, just simply pass the string variable to parameter

Comment: But what if that string is coming from my database sir?

Comment: So? String is String, Whatever its source you can save it, either it coming from DB or from edittext.

Comment: lets suppose, String str=cursor.getColumn("your_column_name");
now db cursor give you a string and you can save str variable in shared preference.

Comment: `Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select userID from tbl_user", null);`<br>
this is from my Cursor is this right sir? O.o

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

follow that tutorial

Comment: res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)))

by using that line you can get your string

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right.

```
String stringValue = "BobSmith";
editor.putString("stringKey", stringValue);
```

Comment: remove "" from stringValue

Comment: whoops thanks, teaches me not to answer questions from my phone.